# Maximal Domain for the following functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I am quite lost with understanding maximal domains. I understand that the numerator when dealing with maximal domains usually are not taken into consideration. Is this true for all cases?

Can anyone help me to understand, how can I better identify, understand maximal domain problems?

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{ln\left(x^3-11x^2+24x\right)}{\sqrt{\left(ln\:x\right)^2-3ln\:x\:+2}}$

Cases like this, my only concern should be the denominator am I right?

I hope someone can help me better understand problem sets like this and going about solving them, the thinking process.

Thank you.

Comment: You can safely disregard the numerator for rational functions, because they are polynomials and can be defined for any real number. However, you cannot disregard the numerator here because the logarithm function is not defined for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the domains of both the numerator and the denominator, then take the intersection of the two domains. In this case (assuming you are working over the real numbers) you need to make sure that all the inputs to $\ln$ are greater than zero, all the inputs to $\sqrt{}$ are greater than zero, and that you don't divide by zero.

Since there is an $\ln x$ term, we must have that $x > 0$. Factor the polynomial in the numerator -- it has roots at $x = 0,3,8$ and is positive on the intervals $(0,3)$ and $(8, \infty)$. For the denominator, let $y = \ln x$ and factor to get $y^2 -3y +2 = (y-1)(y-2)$, which is positive for $y \in (-\infty, 1)$ and $(2, \infty)$, which corresponds to $x \in (0, e)$ and $(e^2, \infty)$. Since $e < 3$ and $e^2 < 8$ the domain is:

$$(0,e) \cup (8, \infty)$$

Wolfram alpha agrees.

Comment: Hi Marc, can I say that because numerator ln(g(x)) has condition of g(x) > 0. Therefore, I have to consider the numerator as well and work it out?

So in other words, x^3-11x^2+24x > 0 I have to solve this solution. Following which the denominator has 
1. 3 ln x + 2
2. (ln x)^2

Please advise.

Comment: Yes, $g(x)$ has to be greater than zero, and so does the entire contents of the square root.